# Can't access my Laravel project through Apache in Docker - /var/www/ directory is empty

Tags: laravel, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I built a Docker image of a Laravel project I'm working on, but when I run the containers (with docker-compose up), I can't access the application.

I'm currently using Docker Toolbox for Windows, so I use the IP from the docker-machine, but all I get is "The requested URL / was not found on this server." (404).

In the Docker Terminal, I get the following warnings:

```
php-apache_1  | AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html] does not exist
php-apache_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

php-apache_1  | [Fri Mar 15 14:04:10.964296 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

I navigated through the directories inside the container (with docker exec -it) and, indeed, the /var/www/html directory doesn't exist, once the /var/www directory is empty, **but it shouldn't be**!!

In the php-apache.dockerfile I copied all my project to the /var/www directory, so it shouldn't be empty.

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, so if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Here is the php-apache.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.9-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && apt-get install -y 
libcurl3-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring tokenizer xml ctype json

RUN mkdir storage &&\
    mkdir storage/logs &&\
    mkdir storage/app &&\
    mkdir storage/framework &&\
    mkdir storage/framework/cache &&\
    mkdir storage/framework/sessions &&\
    mkdir storage/framework/views &&\
    mkdir -p bootstrap/cache

COPY composer.json composer.lock /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . /var/www

RUN curl --silent https://getcomposer.org/installer | php &&\
    composer install

COPY public /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    /var/www/storage \
    /var/www/bootstrap/cache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ontologyFramework
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"   

  php-apache:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      dockerfile: phpapache.dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    links:
      - db
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with your `docker-compose.yml` file. The files you are copying to `/var/www` in your `php-apache.dockerfile` are being hidden by the volume mapping in your `docker-compose.yml` file. Remove the following lines from the compose file:

```
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
```